# 19.04 Nvidia and Wayland option missing

Tags: nvidia, wayland

Just installed 19.04, and then installed the Nvidia 430 drivers. Xorg works fine, but there is no opt to go into Wayland.

Any fix for this?

Comment: It’s still very experimental https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+bugs?field.tag=nvidia-drm.modeset But you can enable it by «nvidia-drm.modeset=1» option (add to  /etc/default/grub) Warning! It's very unstable (use at own risk).